# How to use matching on argument level, is it possible? Guards?

Tags: f#, pattern-guards

for example

```
let When true d = d
let foo = () |> When false
```

So I've got side effect I don't like because it's error: `MatchFailureException`

I know that I can have good side effect here: `let foo = if false then ()`

But warning `Incomplete pattern matches on this expression.` tells me like I can add what I need. I just don't know how or if it possible? Else way why I even can use values as arguments?

*btw: I know that I can write `When b d = if b then d else ()` but question is more general.*

added explain in haskell

```
    let wh :: Bool -> IO () -> IO ()
        wh True f = f
        wh False f = return ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that this is allowed is more of a quirk of the spec, and is really so you can do things like

```
let (a,b) = 1,2
```

Your question isn't particularly clear, but I think you are looking for something like

```
let 1 |2 = 1
```

Essentially the syntax is the same as after match except you don't need the first `|`

Side note, this allows for the craziest piece of F# code that I wrote in a while:

```
let 1 = 2
```

This will compile (with a warning) but fail at runtime.

Comment: but I have it as argument, I've got operator `When` may you show how can I use such syntax with my `When`?

Comment: or... is it just not designed for use as arguments? At least it works when I do `let foo = () |> When true`

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do here.  Are you trying to define a function called when? Or just to use it in some weird way?

Comment: Sorry, I've added explaination of what I want in haskell

Answer (score 4):

When you write something like:

```
let When true d = d
```

You're telling F# to create a function that takes two arguments and you're matching the two arguments against patterns `true` and `d`, respectively. The `true` pattern is incomplete and fails when the input is not a `true` value. The `d` pattern is variable binding and it always succeeds.

The fact that you can use incomplete patterns in arguments of function declarations is not particularly useful (but I suppose you could use a more complex pattern that the compiler just cannot verify).

Incomplete patterns really only make sense when you're using `match` or when you're using `function`. The `function` keyword gives you something like guards in other languages - but it only works with functions taking single argument. If you change `When` to accept a tuple, you can write:

```
let When = function
  | true, f -> f()
  | false, _ -> ()
```

Alternatively, you could reverse the order of arguments (and use currying) as in the answer from Vesa.A.J.K.

Comment: Thank you but I mostly wanted to understand more behavoir where I pass value as in example. I understand that it's currently not supported to work as I want it to work but then is there ways where such things could be useful? Or is it just something incomplete?